# Изменение свойств объекта. Как такое реализовать?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Написать функцию, которая принимает на вход 2 строковых аргумента: Имя и Фамилия. Функция должна вернуть
объект, который будет характеризовать бейджик сотрудника.

> Бейджик состоит из Зх свойств:
>
> - firstName - имя сотрудника,
> - lastName - фамилия сотрудника,
> - fullName - полное имя сотрудника, в формате Фамилия + пробел + Имя.
>
> Эти свойства должны быть доступны для чтения и редактирования:
>
> - Если изменяются firstName или lastName, то fullName также должно быть изменено.
> - Если изменяется fullName, то firstName и lastName также должны быть изменены.
>
> Если полное имя указано в недопустимом формате, то никакие свойства > не должны измениться.

Я хочу создать такую функцию, как мне её реализовать? Я пробовал через геттеры/сеттеры, но у меня не вышло

Мой код:

```
function(firstName, lastName) {
    const badge = {}
    Object.defineProperties(badge, {
      firstName: {
        value: firstName,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true
      },
      lastName: {
        value: lastName,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true
      },
      fullName: {
        get: function() {
          return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
        },
        set: function(value) {
          const split = value.split(' ');
          this.firstName = split[0];
          this.lastName = split[1];
        },
        enumerable: true,
      }
    });
    return badge;
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, который вы писали, и, в котором, по каким-то причинам возникли ошибки.. решать задачки из учебника это не сюда

Comment: изменил вопрос свой

Comment: Вставьте задание текстом, вместо картинки, это будет полезнее для базы знаний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

такое можно сделать с помощью обертки [Proxy](https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy) который может перехватывать изменения для свойств `fistname` и `latname` и присваивать их `fullname`

```js
function getBadge(firstname, lastname) {
  const target = {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    fullname: `${firstname} ${lastname}`,
  }

  const handler = {
    set(target, property, value, receiver) {
      if (property === "firstname" || property === "lastname") {
        target[property] = value
        target.fullname = `${target.firstname} ${target.lastname}`
      }

      return true
    }
  }

  return new Proxy(target, handler)
}

const badge = getBadge("foo", "baz")

console.log(badge)

badge.firstname = "bar"

console.log(badge)
```

Comment: при изменении fullName тоже должна информация изменятся, но суть я понял. Спасибо)